# PHP function not reported as completely covered by PHPUnit when calling multiple times

Tags: php, phpunit, code-coverage

Can someone explain why below function is not reported as completely covered by phpUnit?
Or better yet, explain how to get it reported as completely covered?

```
function itDoesThingsToValue()
{
    static $value = -1;
    if ($value < 0) {
        $value = 1978;
        //Do some more stuff with $value
        //But $value keeps being > 0
    }
    return $value;
}
```

XDebug code coverage reports all the lines as covered when calling this function once or multiple times.

PHPUnit reports the lines as covered when calling it once.

Calling it multiple times (because of different PHPUnit tests), PHPUnit reports the lines inbetween the {} as not covered.

I know the lines between the {} execute only once because of the static variable $value, but imho executed lines should always be reported as covered, regardless if they where skipped at following calls (by following tests).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's still not entirely clear to me, because I don't know the ins and outs of PHPUnit, but this is the case...

The function is called when my class's constructor is called during the first unit test. In this test I declare the function is covered (with @covers annotation).

Somewhere further along, I call this function again in a dataprovider to test another function.

As I thought my function was already tested and covered (within the constructor test), it should be save to use it in the dataprovider.
Actually this causes the lines being reported as not covered.

So my best guess is dataprovider functions run before the unit tests do.

**EDIT:**

**After adding some debug code, it is indeed confirmed *all* data provider methods are executed before any test* methods.**

The following example produces my problem:

```
public function setUp() {
    //Echo the executed testmethod name and 'starting' time into the console.
    echo $this->getName(), ' ', date('H:i:s'), chr(10), chr(13);
}

/**
* @covers MyClass::_construct
* @covers MyClass::myMethod
*/
public function testConstructor() {
    //Do some stuff
}

public function myDataProvider() {
    //Echo the 'starting' time of the data provider method in the console.
    echo 'DataProvider started executing at', ' ', date(H:i:s), chr(10), chr(13);
    $value = MyClass::myMethod; //This causes the lines not being covered
    return [[$value + 1], [$value -1]];
}

/**
* @covers MyClass::AnotherMethod
* @dataprovider myDataProvider
*/
public function testSomethingElse {
    //Do some stuff
}
```

Console Output:

```
Testing started at 21:55 ...
DataProvider started executing at 21:55:46
PHPUnit 5.5.5 by Sebastian Bergmann and contributors.

testConstructor 21:55:47
testSomethingElse 21:55:47
```

My solution is:

```
private $testClassValue;

/**
* @covers MyClass::_construct
* @covers MyClass::myMethod
*/
public function testConstructor() {
    //Do some stuff
    $this->$testClassValue = myClass::value;
}

public function myDataProvider() {
    $value = $this->$testClassValue;
    return [[$value + 1], [$value -1]];
}

/**
* @covers MyClass::AnotherMethod
* @dataprovider myDataProvider
*/
public function testSomethingElse {
    //Do some stuff
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I ran your code and agree, it is strange behavior, showing a non-existent line at the last`}` as not covered (83% coverage).  I found the following in [PHPUnit documentation for Code Coverage](https://phpunit.de/manual/current/en/code-coverage-analysis.html) under **Edge Cases**:

```
// Because it is "line based" and not statement base coverage
// one line will always have one coverage status
if (false) this_function_call_shows_up_as_covered();

// Due to how code coverage works internally these two lines are special.
// This line will show up as non executable
if (false)
    // This line will show up as covered because it is actually the 
    // coverage of the if statement in the line above that gets shown here!
    will_also_show_up_as_covered();

// To avoid this it is necessary that braces are used
if (false) {
    this_call_will_never_show_up_as_covered();
}
```

So I moved the last } up to the return line and it started reporting 100% coverage.

```
function itDoesThingsToValue(){
static $value = -1;
if ($value < 0) {
    $value = 1978;
    //Do some more stuff with $value
    //But $value keeps being > 0
}
return $value;}
```

Comment: I've seen that, but it's not about the last line. All lines between {} aren't covered. Still they're executed the first time and of course not consecutive times because of the static variable. My guess is PHPUnit starts and stops xdebug's code coverage for every test instead of starting at the first test and stopping after the last.

Comment: I see...my configuration is that I have xdebug on (I can step through executing tests), running only with PHPUnit code coverage,  and with the static variable, I get 100% coverage (even with two different unit tests calling it separately).  Maybe that help you isolate the problem.

Comment: Thank you for your interest in my problem. FYI... Further research led me to the answer I posted and marked as accepted.